# A buffer failed while allocating 10484320 bytes

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

When I run the following package, it completes every task successfully until loading into the destination where 0 rows are written. I reduced the buffer size but still didn't work.
Any clue on how to solve this. I get the following error messages

> "A buffer failed while allocating 10484320 bytes", "SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED"

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error means your system is running out of memory before the buffer pool has reached it's limit.  There are two data flow properties you want to look at:

- `DefaultMaxBufferSize` - Sets the maximum memory usage for buffer
- `DefaultBufferMaxRows` - Sets the maximum rows to buffer

If you lower the `DefaultBufferMaxRows` it will probably be enough to avoid the issue without getting too specific.  If you know exactly how much memory you have available for the buffer (or close), you could instead lower the `DefaultMaxBufferSize` to just below your available memory.